# How do I properly define screens for React Native Navigation? (Error: Couldn't find any screens for the navigator. Have you defined any screens...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

First off I have looked at [Error: Couldn't find any screens for the navigator. Have you defined any screens as its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391386/error-couldnt-find-any-screens-for-the-navigator-have-you-defined-any-screens)

And that person had an array of screens that was not yet filled. I have defined my screens and using them directly.

I'm new to React Native, and I'm trying to add navigation to the basic template. It's not going well.

My code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */
import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <Button
            title="Go to Jane's profile"
            onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
            }
        />
    );
};

const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    return <Text>This is {route.params.name}'s profile</Text>;
    <Button
        title="Go to Home"
        onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('Home')
        }
    />
};

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };
    
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  component={HomeScreen}
                  options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
                  key="1"
              />
              <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} key='2' />
          </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

At which point I get the error:

```
Error: Couldn't find any screens for the navigator. Have you defined any screens as its children?
```

I assume there's something basic I'm missing.

Comment: i try you example it works, can't find that error!

Comment: Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/basic-app) out... Works perfectly fine

Comment: @KartikeyVaish, cheers. That was definately part of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the component that is your screen need to return only one element.

If you need to return more than one element you can wrap it in the <> </> balise or any other component.

```js
const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text>This is {route.params.name}'s profile</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. But I think my real problem was unfamiliarity with Visual studio. Coming from Intellij I'm still getting used to having to manually save files before re-building. #feelingthedumb